# Discord API: View guild channels information with Oauth2 guilds scope

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a call to `/guilds/guild.id/channels` endpoint after retrieving a user's guild data that is provided after they successfully authenticate with my app using  the Discord's OAuth flow.

My OAuth permissions include `email` and `guilds`.

After receiving an access_token I am able to make a call to `/users/@me/guilds`. However, when I try to iterate over this to access each guild's list of channels using the `/guilds/guild.id/channels` endpoint I receive a `{"message": "401: Unauthorized", "code": 0}`. I pass the same access_token in the header of this request.

My question is about the limitations of the Discord API when authenticating with OAuth. The [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#bot-vs-user-accounts) says

> Unlike the normal OAuth2 flow, bot accounts have full access to all API routes without using bearer tokens

**So can I make an API call to `/guilds/guild.id/channels` using my access_token?**

Or do I have to do this through a bot? And if a bot is required then that means in order to make a call to `/guilds/guild.id/channels` the bot must first be added to the guild, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you falsely assumed that the `guilds` OAuth2 scope will give you full access to the guilds of the user. This is not the case, the `guilds` scope only grants the access token permission to view a list of all the user's guilds and basic information of these guilds (guild ID, avatar, name, flags, the user's permission, and whether the user's the owner).

This does not include giving you access to see the guild's channels. The only endpoint `guilds` scope gives you is `/users/@me/guilds` which you already know. I believe this is due to user privacy concerns since it unnecessarily lets you to view the channels list from non-related guilds. Most cases when the `guilds` scope is used, it is to verify if the user's in a certain guild; useful for bot dashboards.

The only way to retrieve a list of channels requires you to have a bot in the guild and use the `/guilds/<guild.id>/channels` while identifying as your bot.

To see what the OAuth2 scopes actually grants you, it's documented here: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#shared-resources-oauth2-scopes.

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense. I'll look to leverage the /guilds/<guild.id>/channels endpoint using a bot. really appreciate your help here.

Comment: @dberning You're welcome! Good luck continuing making your bot. If you feel this answers your question, consider marking the green checkmark next to the answer to mark your question as solved. :)

Comment: @Taku could you clarify this part: 'while identifying as your bot'

Comment: to identify as a bot you need to use 'Authorization: Bot <your API key>'